# Difference between force.com and salesforce.com?

Tags: force.com

What the difference between the two?  This description seems to be a bit out of date and underspecified.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Difference-Between-Salesforce-com-and-Force-com/td-p/138874

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IMHO this is the best aswer: https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000btOsEAI

> There are at least three different things going on in your post, from
>   what I can tell
>
> First of all, Salesforce.com is built on the Force.com platform - they
>   are more or less interchangeable from a technical standpoint.  It's a
>   mere matter of marketing semantics.  Force.com applies to the
>   infrastructure and codebase that is the foundation for the entire
>   Salesforce solution.  They are enforcing the Force.com concept more so
>   because Salesforce can do so much more than CRM nowadays.
>
> Secondly, regarding the functionality situation.  In this case I think
>   you are referring to the Force.com Edition in comparison to the
>   standard Salesforce.com Editions (Professional, Enterprise, etc.).  In
>   this case, yes there is a difference.  The Force.com Edition (or
>   Platform Edition, depending on the marketing materials you have in
>   hand, what day of the week it is and whether or not your sneakers have
>   green stripes) is a standard Enterprise Edition (if you buy in
>   conjunction with a full Enterprise Edition) minus the CRM
>   functionality - so no Leads, Opportunities, etc. (as far as I know). 
>   This Platform Edition is aimed at providing customers with the
>   "platform" on which to build custom applications - for companies that
>   do not so much use Salesforce for the CRM.
>
> And lastly, regarding the Developer Edition accounts you created with
>   interests in Salesforce.com customization and Force.com platform -
>   again, just another marketing ploy.  Salesforce uses the preferences
>   you set to send you more targeted information via email regarding the
>   topics of interest to you.

Answer (score 19):

Different licences. Salesforce.com licences are for the Sales Cloud CRM product. Force.com is the platform everything is built on, and you can buy Force.com licences to build a custom product that does not utilise the standard CRM features and objects, such as Opportunities for instance.

Comment: Actually, Accounts and Contacts are the only two CRM objects that you do have access to with Force.com. [Data Sheet](http://www.force.com/export/sites/force/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_Forcedotcom_EdCompare.pdf)

Comment: Good point! It's been a while since I played with a force.com licence only :)