# what is the difference between salesforce object and force.com object

Tags: rest-api

I am reading through force.com rest api developer guide http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/quickstart.htm

> Obtain detailed information about a Salesforce object such as an Account or a custom object.
>
> Obtain detailed information about Force.com objects, such as User or a custom object.

Can anybody explain what is the difference between salesforce object and force.com object?

Comment: I think you can find the answer here : [Difference between Salesforce.com and Force.com][1]


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/difference-between-force-com-and-salesforce-com

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between Salesforce and Force Objects.

You should look for difference between [Standard and Custom Object.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_concepts.htm)

> Objects already created for you by Salesforce are called standard
>   objects. Objects you create in your organization are called custom
>   objects.

Comment: thankx...what is the difference between standard and custom object

Comment: Why would salesforce have list it separately?

Comment: Agree with @Prady. If there is no real difference, there wouldn't have been two lines mentioning each separately.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is mentioned in the link provided by @Martin Borthiry, Objects created by Salesforce is Standard Object and objects created by user is Custom Objects.

And a Standard Object can never be a child object in M/D relationhip

Standard Objects cannot be deleted

Custom Fields can be made mandatory or optional based on business requirments, But with Standard Objects fileds like in Contact Page - Account Name can never be made Optional - Standard Objects mandatory fields cannot be made optional.

Likewise there are many difference between Standard & Custom objects