# What is the specific feature delta between Salesforce.com and Force.com app licenses?

Tags: force.com

I am aware of the differences between Salesforce.com and Force.com but I am unsure what the specific, granular feature differences between the two licenses are.

For example, what standard objects can one have with a Force.com app license? It seems to be Opportunity, Account and User only but some say Case as well. And if Case, then are cases to be sent externally and internally supported or just internally?

It seems that such a feature delta document doesn't actually exist and to get it, one would need to liaise with the Salesforce Account Executive.

I am curious to see if there is a specific and granular feature delta document that is available to view?

Answer (score 0):

you can find these references useful

1. [Difference between force.com and salesforce.com?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/difference-between-force-com-and-salesforce-com)
2. https://www.zarantech.com/blog/difference-between-salesforce-com-and-force-com/

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! While these links may answer the question, it's better if you could quote the relevant parts of those links and include them in your answer. Links have a tendency to go dead after some time, so quoting the relevant portions means this answer could still be useful if/when the links go dead. You can [edit] your answer to make these changes.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for this wonderful suggestion. I would make this into practice from now. I've used link over here as this is a wide topic to understand and the readers can have a thorough understanding.